# Making gvim 'instance-only'

Tags: command-line, gvim

I want to make gvim be 'instance-only', i.e., know of an option or something that opens the file as a tab on my already-open gvim instance instead of opening a new one.

Example to clarify: suppose I have a gvim window open with one file, module1.c. Supposing I'm on a terminal, what command do I have to enter in order to make 'module2.c' open in the same window that now has module1.c?

PS: I'm aware that there's a -p option that allows me to open multiple files in multiple tabs. But what I'm looking for is a way to open a new tab from OUTSIDE gvim AFTER it is running already.

How to do it? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I want to make gvim be 'instance-only', i.e., know of an option or something that opens the file as a tab on my already-open gvim instance instead of opening a new one.*

Allow me to just clarify something here ... in vim, tabs are not what people would expect them to be. In most programs they are an "instance" of a file (one tab/one file), but in vim they are merely a "viewpoint" into which you can have several vim windows, each one holding whatever you put in it.

Vim, when opening a  file, opens it in a buffer. One buffer for every file. You can view the list of opened buffers with

```
:ls
```

*Example to clarify: suppose I have a gvim window open with one file, module1.c. Supposing I'm on a terminal, what command do I have to enter in order to make 'module2.c' open in the same window that now has module1.c?*

Again, we have a terminology problem. For the sake of discussion, I'll assume you mean "window" as in a windows window, and not a vim internal window.
If you wish to open a file in an already opened gvim instance try

```
gvim first_file.dat
gvim --remote-tab second_file.dat
```

This can easily be shortened by putting it in a .bat file (if you're on windows), and then you don't have to type the "--..." part over and over again.

*PS: I'm aware that there's a -p option that allows me to open multiple files in multiple tabs. But what I'm looking for is a way to open a new tab from OUTSIDE gvim AFTER it is running already.*

Interesting, I didn't know about that one :)

*How to do it? Is it even possible?*

Tell if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I was looking for! =D Also, you can shorten the command with a shell script put on the /usr/bin folder (I called mine 'gvimt')

Comment: excellent, thank you.  I did alias=vim='/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Vim/vim73/gvim.exe --remote-tab' in cygwin

Comment: You can do "Function g{ param($file) gvim --remote-silent $file }" in Powershell

Answer (score 3):

Vim can do this when run in clientserver mode, if it was compiled with the *+clientserver* option.

Launch the first vim instance with the *--servername* option:

```
gvim --servername FILES --remote-silent file.txt
```

Now, you can open further files in this instance by either providing *--servername*, or with just the *--remote* option.

```
gvim --remote file2.txt

gvim --servername FOOBAR --remote file3.txt
```

Taken from the vim manual documentation [on the clientserver mode](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/remote.html#clientserver). Afaik, the new files are opened as buffers on the active tab. I'm not sure if vim can be configured to open the incoming files in new tabs.